# edit xamdatagrid row color

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I know how to change the color of the text from an xamdatagrid. What I do is to define a style in the xaml file and I add: igDP:CellValuePresenter

and then on the InitializeRecord method I get each record and use:

record.FieldLayout.Fields["Category"].Settings.CellValuePresenterStyle = Style

What C# code can I use to accomplish the same but Using igDP:DataRecordCellArea on the xaml file?

thanks

Comment: [The article](https://mytorrey.com/2011/05/08/conditionally-formatting-cells-in-xamdatagrid-2/)
in the previous answer is incomplete. I was not able to use it as it's missing two section examples. Instead I found the following from Infragistics that has a downloadable example, that worked:
[Infragistics Cell Color Example](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/f/ultimate-ui-for-wpf/91509/change-background-color-of-xamdatagrid-cell-based-on-cell-value)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://mytorrey.com/2011/05/08/conditionally-formatting-cells-in-xamdatagrid-2/) explains very well what to do in order to change a cell's background or foreground color based on some conditional value in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the XamDataGrid's RecordsInViewChanged event and iterate through the Records and set their DataRecordCellArea Style or not like this:

foreach (var item in (sender as XamDataGrid).GetRecordsInView(true))
{

```
DataRecordCellArea drca = Utilities.GetDescendantFromType(DataRecordPresenter.FromRecord(item), typeof(DataRecordCellArea), true) as DataRecordCellArea;
drca.Style = ....your style
```

}

Also in the future I can suggest you post your questions, related to Infragistics controls, here:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/

where you will get an answer from an Infragistics expert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the Style to all Records, a better appraoch is to add this Style in the XamDataGrid's Resources:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid >
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
</igDP:XamDataGrid
```